# What is the white swirl in my bread and is it safe?

Tags: bread, wheat

I just bought a loaf of wheat bread and in an attempt to use it I noticed that there are thick white "swirls" throughout the whole loaf.

[image]

I thought it might be that it was not mixed properly but I have not found anything stating what it could be.

I am just wondering what it is and if it is safe to eat?

Comment: I would guess it's just poorly mixed dough but the photo isn't high enough resolution to be sure.

Comment: @Dyana : Can you please take the bread out of the polythene and then take its pic and provide to us so as to understand it better as white swirls are not exactly visible when the bread is in polythene..

Comment: @Sweet72 Yes, I have updated the photo. That is the best I could get it.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're right that it wasn't mixed properly.

Many types of whole wheat bread are actually partially whole wheat flour, partially white flour. That could just be some white flour that didn't get mixed.

Alternatively, it could have been a clump of flour that either didn't get hydrated or didn't get yeast mixed in, so it didn't rise, and thus didn't bake the same.

It could also be some dough conditioners or wheat gluten that didn't mix.

Assuming there isn't some other reason to doubt it (e.g., its old, was stored improperly, tastes or smells weird, etc.) I'd guess it's safe.

Best bet is to call the manufacturer, or just return it and get another...